# How to persist a variable value in a cascading SP without changing all SPs signature?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a parent SP which call 4-5 SPs within it. I want to pass a variable from the parent SP to the last SP. I am looking for a solution by which I don't have to update the signature of all the SPs and get that value in the last SP.
As of now, I can think of two approaches:
1- Using CONTEXT_INFO function of SQL Server.
2- Using Temp table.

Is there any other cleaner approach anyone can think of?

Comment: I don't understand how CONTEXT_INFO would help you here. A temp table would work. You could declare it in the first procedure and read it in the last one. Be warned though, this approach is pretty brittle. You would create a situation where the last procedure is not runnable by itself.

Comment: Why not simply add an optional parameter to the last procedure??